# How can I make a github action fail/pass according to its coverage?

Tags: python, github-actions, pytest-cov

I have a python project where I created some tests using pytest and pytest-cov. I want to add a github action that will run the tests with coverage and fail if the coverage is below some arbitrary x number. What is the best way to go about it?

Comment: See https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/development-tools-for-github-actions#setting-an-actions-status-using-exit-codes and `pytest-cov`'s `--cov-fail-under=MIN` flag

Comment: Cool so the `--cov-fail-under` flag looks real useful. But how do I change the status code of a github action from within the workflow file?

Comment: Never worked specifically with GitHub actions but the way it usually goes is that any command ran from a CI pipeline (Jenkins, BitBucket pipelines, GitHub actions, etc) is checked for its exit code - if it's non-zero, the action is considered a failure. The `--cov-fail-under` flag simply causes the `pytest-cov` invocation to exit with a non-zero exit code (that what is meant by "fail")

Comment: Is there a fail flag for coverage.py using unittest?